# Adding language (Dutch) to LibreOffice Writer

Tags: language, libreoffice, openoffice, dictionary, extension

I'm having trouble doing a spelling check in LibreOffice (in Dutch). It supposed to come with the package but it doesn't show in my screen (see image: [no abc mentioned before 'dutch'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIHTD.png)).

I tried:

1. installing a tool called 'LanguageTool' (plus Java). This however only seems to allow for grammatical corrections, no spelling (image: [no errors for nonsense words or spelling errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EagkO.png))
2. downloading dictionaries. But I don't understand how to connect those dictionaries to the software (image: [extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgEUu.png)).

I'm hesitant weather redownloading the software will solve the issue, as my understanding is that Dutch should be included (now only English, Spanish and French). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Charles